# Active MQ Dummy Queue Requirement Or Intercerpt Message before pushing to Queue

Tags: jms, apache-camel, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We have got requirement where we have to push some of the message for offline implementation , now we have online /offline hybrid installation, for online we are pushing messages to queue but for offline we still want to push queue but read messages for offline and store it in local file system so that 
we can store it in file system and give offline system to manually process it by putting it in their queue.
I am wondering if we have dummy queue kind of thing in active mq where we can put all the offline message and read it store on the file system and delete it from queue after that .

I read here that a camel interceptor can be used in such conditions but need help if some one can elaborate it :
http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Research ActiveMQ some more as it has mirrored queues or you can use the Camel wire-tap to send a duplicate message to that dummy queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to handle such things is probably through the [Camel Broker Component](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-camel-component.html).

It can be used to make copies of messages, alter destination and what not.